# How to connect to a artifactory repository using docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, artifactory, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a artifactory repository set up in the address :

```
https://artifactory.***.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-*****/python/3.6-strech/
```

It needs `username : aie-dkr` and `password : ersghshsshsh` to get logged in. Now I am trying to log in to this repository , tag the image through `dev_build.sh` file. I must be doing something wrong as it constantly throws me image pull failed: Failed to apply default image tag error. Does someone has any idea to correctly configure my file ?

```
echo "===== docker tag ===="
docker tag https://artifactory.***.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python/3.6-strech:latest
echo "===== docker login ===="
docker login $ARTIFACTORY_URL -u $QA_ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $QA_ARTIFACTORY_ACCESS_TOKEN
#docker login https://artifactory.***.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/
echo "===== docker push Dev ===="
docker push aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory.***.com/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
```

Error which I am receiving

Waiting for pod sai/runner-dan3u2t-project-9879-concurrent-0zdmgf to be running, status is Pending
ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"
ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"

WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech"

Comment: Docker image names don't have the `https://` URL prefix, if that helps your problem.

Comment: You said that the error occurs during image pull, however, above, you are not pulling anything. Is it the case that you run the dev_build.sh  and  assume that it worked and then when you try to pull it errors  out. In that case, as @DavidMaze suggested, it is the tagging issue, so, try omitting https:// from your docker tag GUN (Globally Unique Name)

Comment: Please share the complete error message you are getting

Comment: I have added the error message